# How to resolve random crashes with Cloudera libhdfs.so?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, cloudera-cdh, libhdfs

Getting SIGSEGV crashes in libjvm.so when using Cloudera's libhdfs.so. These seem to occur at random points given the stack traces but most commonly during Java function Monitor::wait().

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**Environment**:

- CentOS 6.7
- Linux 2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 22 22:00:00 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- GNU libc 2.12
- java version "1.7.0_79"
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
- Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.11.0

I have tried using Java 1.8 but didn't help.  I don't have the option of using a newer version than CentOS 6.7.

**GDB**:

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f862f63b0f3 in Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f862f63b0f3 in Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#1  0x00007f862f8022f4 in VMThread::execute(VM_Operation*) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#2  0x00007f862f1600d8 in BiasedLocking::revoke_and_rebias(Handle, bool, Thread*) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#3  0x00007f862f7783d2 in ObjectSynchronizer::fast_enter(Handle, BasicLock*, bool, Thread*) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#4  0x00007f862f4520a1 in InterpreterRuntime::monitorenter(JavaThread*, BasicObjectLock*) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#5  0x00007f8628dbaba0 in ?? ()
#6  0x00007ffe672c1290 in ?? ()
#7  0x00007f8628dbab6c in ?? ()
#8  0x00000007aeae5610 in ?? ()
#9  0x00000007aeae5610 in ?? ()
#10 0x00007ffe672c1240 in ?? ()
#11 0x0000000702434dba in ?? ()
#12 0x00007ffe672c12b8 in ?? ()
#13 0x00000007024b38b0 in ?? ()
#14 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) info threads
20 Thread 0x7f8624a6a700 (LWP 26482)  pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_wait.S:183
19 Thread 0x7f8624e6e700 (LWP 26417)  pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_timedwait.S:239
18 Thread 0x7f8626485700 (LWP 26409)  pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_wait.S:183
17 Thread 0x7f8627d93700 (LWP 26403)  pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_wait.S:183
16 Thread 0x7f8627e94700 (LWP 26402)  pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_wait.S:183
15 Thread 0x7f8627c92700 (LWP 26404)  pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_wait.S:183
14 Thread 0x7f8626788700 (LWP 26406)  pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_wait.S:183
13 Thread 0x7f8624d6d700 (LWP 26418)  pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_timedwait.S:239
12 Thread 0x7f8626687700 (LWP 26407)  pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_wait.S:183
11 Thread 0x7f86251b5700 (LWP 26414)  pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_timedwait.S:239
10 Thread 0x7f8626384700 (LWP 26410)  pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_wait.S:183
 9 Thread 0x7f862517c700 (LWP 26416)  pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_wait.S:183
 8 Thread 0x7f8626586700 (LWP 26408)  sem_wait () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sem_wait.S:86
 7 Thread 0x7f8626283700 (LWP 26411)  pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_wait.S:183
 6 Thread 0x7f8624b6b700 (LWP 26420)  pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_timedwait.S:239
 5 Thread 0x7f8626182700 (LWP 26412)  pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_timedwait.S:239
 4 Thread 0x7f8624c6c700 (LWP 26429)  pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_timedwait.S:239
 3 Thread 0x7f8627f95700 (LWP 26401)  pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_wait.S:183
 2 Thread 0x7f8626889700 (LWP 26405)  0x00007f862f707f6e in SafepointSynchronize::begin() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
* 1 Thread 0x7f863057e720 (LWP 26396)  0x00007f862f63b0f3 in Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
```

**JStack**

```
----------------- 26405 -----------------
0x00007f862f707f6e  SafepointSynchronize::begin() + 0x25e
0x00007f862f80273f  VMThread::loop() + 0x1bf
0x00007f862f802bc0  VMThread::run() + 0x70
0x00007f862f679ca8  java_start(Thread*) + 0x108
----------------- 26396 -----------------
0x00007f862f63b0f3  Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) + 0x313
0x00007f862f8022f4  VMThread::execute(VM_Operation*) + 0x324
0x00007f862f1600d8  BiasedLocking::revoke_and_rebias(Handle, bool, Thread*) + 0x178
0x00007f862f7783d2  ObjectSynchronizer::fast_enter(Handle, BasicLock*, bool, Thread*) + 0x42
0x00007f862f4520a1  InterpreterRuntime::monitorenter(JavaThread*, BasicObjectLock*) + 0xa1
0x00007f8628dbaba0  * java.lang.Thread.interrupt() bci:18 line:955 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007f8628da2058  * org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.close(boolean) bci:40 line:943 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007f8628da2058  * org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.closeThreads(boolean) bci:5 line:2596 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007f8628da2058  * org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.closeImpl() bci:142 line:2678 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007f8628da2058  * org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.close() bci:28 line:2621 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007f8628da2058  * org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close() bci:11 line:72 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007f8628da2058  * org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.close() bci:4 line:106 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007f8628d9c4e7  <StubRoutines>
0x00007f862f458e95  JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*) + 0x365
0x00007f862f4578f8  JavaCalls::call(JavaValue*, methodHandle, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*) + 0x28
0x00007f862f492384  jni_invoke_nonstatic(JNIEnv_*, JavaValue*, _jobject*, JNICallType, _jmethodID*, JNI_ArgumentPusher*, Thread*) + 0x2b4
0x00007f862f4a0ffc  jni_CallVoidMethodV + 0xec
Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```